# AdControl stops updating after navigating back in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, ads

Hello I'm updating a MVVM Windows phone 8.1 app to UWP and have run into a problem.

The adControl correctly shows ads when the app is lunched, but when the user then navigates to a different page and then back the adControl simply stops updating.

I have set:

```
IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True"
```

and

```
AutoRefreshIntervalInSeconds="60"
```

i also tried checking

```
ErrorOccurred="AdControl_ErrorOccurred"
```

but nothing fires here after navigation back.

I am using the

`SystemNavigationManager` to let the user navigate back.

Comment: This is a good thing. Adverts suck.

Comment: @MikeEason Unfortunately for some it is the only viable revenue model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone still struggling with this bug that Microsoft has still not on 28-03-2016 fixed, what I did was use admeditator instead(it also has the bug), and then call the following on page navigation.

```
protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        this.AdMediator_ECB2E3.Disable();
        base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.AdMediator_ECB2E3.Resume();
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
```

Comment: Also disabling NavigationCacheMode for the page helps.

Comment: Wasnt successful using this for an UWP app. Disabling NavigationCacheMode isnt an option for me. Also "Disable()" is now called "Suspend()"

Comment: Hello tipa The app side mediator is no longer recomended to use it is done server side now, see  https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/monetize/update-your-app-to-the-latest-advertising-libraries

Comment: Also I don't know if it is Suspend() now but at time of writhing it was Disable().