# Workaround now broken for: UWP AdControl blank after PopAsync in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, ads

"Xamarin Forms project using the Microsoft Advertising AdControl. The control works fine when a page is opened, but when a page is shown again after a PopAsync of a page on top of it, the AdControl is blank, and stays blank after that."

This is an [old problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50037580/uwp-adcontrol-blank-after-popasync-in-xamarin-forms), also 4+ years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068329/adcontrol-stops-updating-after-navigating-back-in-uwp), but the workaround, which (worked in 4.1 and earlier) is now broken in forms 4.2 & 4.3, was to call InitializeComponent() again in OnAppearing.  It's broken now because duplicate names cause a runtime exception.

Other than getting Microsoft to fix the bug, what's the correct way to get the adControl to work after a popasync?

Answer (score 0):

I try to use Xamarin.forms latest version 4.3.0.908675to test, and I have error message:

An element with the same key already exists in NameScope

But I use the xamarin.forms version 4.0.0.709238, it works fine.

Workaround:

Install Xamarin.Forms version 4.0.0.709238 instead the latest version.

I will report this bug for MS, you can also report this bug in Github, so MS will see it to try to fix.

Comment: Yes, realize it works fine in 4.1 and earlier (broken 4.2 and 4.3,) but I don't want to be stuck on 4.1 forever.  I reported the bug to MS/Xamarin.forms on github and the response was : "We're not going to fix that". and closed the bug.  I didn't report the advertising bug since it's been around for 4+ years or more, but maybe that's a good idea. Thx

Answer (score 0):

From Xamarin.forms on github:

"if you want this to work, set the Namescope of your view to null before invoking InitializeComponent a second time."
they added...
"but mostly: don't call InitializeComponent() twice"

It be a more complete answer if anyone can elaborate and provide an example of setting the Namescope of the view to null.